# How to exclude repeated keys in dictionary of dictionaries when reading a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have made a code so far that reads a csv file and returns the data in the form of nested dictionaries. The first column of the table in the csv file holds the keys and its keys values are the values of the same row.

I want to transform my code so it can exclude a key and its values if it is subsequently repeated in this column with the same string name. For example, if I have twice the string "Name" in a column I want to exclude the first "Name" as a key field and replace it (along with all its values) by the subsequent "Name" which may be some lines after.

My code so far:

```
def dict_of_dicts (filename, keyfield):
    tabledict= {}
    with open (filename, "rt", newline='') as csv_file:
        csvreader=csv.DictReader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)
        for row in csvreader:
            tabledict[row[keyfield]]=row
    return tabledict
```

Comment: Please show us some sample input and output.

Comment: What Alex said. Your description is a bit confusing & ambiguous. If we could see a small sample of input & associated output it would make things a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
import csv

# implementation following

def dict_of_dicts (filename, keyfield):
    tabledict = {}
    with open(filename, 'rt', newline='') as csv_file:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)
        for row in csvreader:
            if len(row) < 1:
                continue
            tabledict[row[0]] = row[1:]
    return tabledict

# example following

with open('test.csv', 'w') as fd:
    w = csv.writer(fd)
    w.writerows([
        ["Name","Andrew","John","Mike"],
        ["Age","20","25","26"],
        ["Weight","65","76","80"],
        ["Height","1.75","1.8","1","9"],
        ["Age","21","26","27"]
    ])

print(dict_of_dicts('test.csv', 'Name'))
```

The output is:

```
{'Name': ['Andrew', 'John', 'Mike'], 'Age': ['21', '26', '27'], 'Weight': ['65', '76', '80'], 'Height': ['1.75', '1.8', '1', '9']}
```